# Multi column WHERE IN AND

Tags: mysql

I am currently using MySQL (5.7) to query a table of members.

When I do a query like:

```
SELECT fname, lname, added
FROM Members
WHERE ((fname, lname) IN (('firstname one', 'lastname one'), ('firstname one', 'lastname one')));
```

It works as expected and a list of members first names, last names, and the date they were added is shown.

But if I want to narrow down when a member was added, e.g.

```
SELECT fname, lname, added
FROM Members
WHERE ((fname, lname) IN (('firstname one', 'lastname one'), ('firstname two', 'lastname two')))
AND added => '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND added <= '2014-06-01 00:00:00';
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=> '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND added <= '2014-06-01 00:00:00'' at line 3
```

If I try an IN clause on a single column:

```
...
WHERE fname IN ('firstname one', 'firstname two')
AND added => '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND added<= '2014-06-01 00:00:00'
```

It works OK. So the issues seems to be with an IN clause over two (or more) columns.

Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I see that you use `Timestamp` in the last query and `added` in the second one. Typo? What type is `added` column?

Comment: yes, that was a typo.Corrected now, thanks.

Comment: `AND added =>`  is a typo. Why not use `between`

Comment: added is a DateTime. Both fname and lname are VARCHARs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Drew, I changed:

```
AND added => '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND added <= '2014-06-01 00:00:00';
```

to:

```
AND added BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-06-01 00:00:00';
```

and it worked.